# How to create the View for an iOS telnet client?

Tags: ios, terminal, telnet

I want to create a telnet client that can be used primary with a special temperature control device in my network which presents a telnet-based menu for configuration.

I've created some simple iOS apps before, but never created custom Views. What I want to create is a terminal-like window that can print (and wrap) text, scroll and of course handle user input, which should be entered at the current position.

What kind of approach would you suggest to create that kind of interface? I've heard of "Core Text", might this be an option? Should I better use OpenGL for that? Is it possible to enable "copy and paste" with text that is displayed using these methods without reinventin the wheel?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The easiest way is probably to use UITextView. It seems to do everything you'd need, and allows styled text under iOS 6.

Doing your own would be hard, but yeah, I'd use Core Text. You'd have to reinvent the wheel to get copy and paste working, but you might be able to leverage some of the UIResponder, UIMenuItem, and other text system features.